# In Spring MVC, is singleton bean thread-safe?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Assuming we have the following bean:

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    private String name;

    public String sayHello(String name) {
        this.name = name;

        return "hello, " + this.name;
    }
}
```

In Spring MVC, if several users call `sayHello()` method at the same time but pass different parameters, will they get the correct greeting response?

I just want to know will multiple threads modify the same name variable concurrently?
Thanks very much!

Comment: This component is not thread-safe by virtue of being stateful. A good rule of thumb is to avoid storing state in Spring beans - makes life *much* easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344009/815227).

Summing up... Both concepts are completely different since thread-safe is related to the code of the bean itself and has nothing to do with its instantiation.

I hope it helps.

** UPDATE after comment **

You may try something like this:

**Greetings.java**

```
public class Greetings {
    private String name;

    public Greetings (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String sayHello () {
        return "Hello, " + this.name;
    }
}
```

**AccountService.class**

```
@Service
public class AccountService {
    public String sayHello (String name) {
        Greetings greetings = new Greetings(name);
        return greetings.sayHello();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've read this post already. I just want to know will multiple threads modify the same `name` variable concurrently?

Comment: Yep! I believe you're mixing concepts. Perhaps you could instance a new object (the one that contains the string name) every time an `SayHello` method is called. That way you are sure that it's thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is change the scope from `singleton` to `request`.

Comment: This would be suboptimal if `AccountService` was costly to create, and service components usually are. Consider reorganizing your code to move state into a different layer.